# Jasypt with spring 4.0

Tags: spring-security, jasypt

I am using spring security in my application through XML configuration.

This is my password encoder bean

```
<b:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
    <b:constructor-arg value="ThisIsASecretSoChangeMe" />
</b:bean>
```

I want to replace it with Jasypt encryption.
How to integrate jasypt 1.9 with spring security 4.0.1.RELEASE?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring-boot use this dependeny in pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in your application.yml or application.properties file just put the Encrypted password enclosed with ENC() instead of plainpassword. Example

```
password:
    encrypted:
        password: ENC(nZ3U2bdJ05FHp1LYQbAVvDKkVs8Pi3Ke)

jasypt:
    encryptor:
        password: IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree
```

Before this you need to generate this encrypted password from your plaintext password and the jasypt.encryptor.password(similar to salt, in this case IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree). This can be done by something like this

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="PasswordToBeEncrypted" password=<SecretKeyToEncryptDecrypt> algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

or torough a java code. Here is a rough draft.

```
public class Md5Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        String password = "plaintextpassword";

        BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        textEncryptor.setPassword("IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree  ");
        String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt(password);
        System.out.println(myEncryptedText);
        BasicTextEncryptor textDecryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        textDecryptor.setPassword("IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree  ");
        String plainText = textDecryptor.decrypt("QBPaH8HKE8JDaeIpJk66Kc8nGHtBfY+L");
        System.out.println(plainText);
    }
  }
```

Comment: where did you use `IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree` after setting it as `jasypt.encryptor.password` ?

Comment: What does `input="PasswordToBeEncrypted"` exactly do?

Comment: If I don't have class `Md5Test` will my app work? I mean just by injecting 'jasypt' as a dependency and generating the password, everything should work properly?

Comment: edited my code a bit. `IfYouAreGoodAtSomethingNeverDoItForFree`, this is like a secret key which you use to encrypt and decrypt. This can be anything. Md5Test is a simple example. Where I have shown how to generate encrypted passwords(using jasypt classes) which needs to be put inside `ENC(..)`. You can generate encrypted password in many other ways. check their documentation. This class need not and should not be in the project

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer other way to do is using `java -cp ....` command. In this command `input="PasswordToBeEncrypted"` is the same as `String password = "plaintextpassword";` in the java program

Answer (score 0):

generated encrypted string from command does not give desired result as it can not encrypt special chards like "!".and gives error "event not found"

> KAD@ashutosh MINGW64 ~/Desktop
>
> $ java -cp
>   ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar
>   org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI
>   input="Test!email30#password" password="some_salt"
>   algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
>
> bash: !email30#password: event not found

Here is an example using `org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor`
This is a utility class for easily performing `high-strength encryption of texts`.

This class internally holds a `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` configured this way:

- Algorithm: `PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256`.
- Key obtention iterations: `1000`.

The required steps to use it are:

1. Create an instance (using new).
2. Set a password (using setPassword(String) or setPasswordCharArray(char[])).
3. Perform the desired encrypt(String) or decrypt(String) operations.

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can use jasypt latest 2.1.2(with boot 2.1.1) or `jasypt-1.9.3.jar`.

**Java Code:**

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class JasyptPasswordEcryptor {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String password = "Test!email30#password";

    AES256TextEncryptor encryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword("some_salt");
    String myEncryptedText = encryptor.encrypt(password);
    System.out.println("Encrypted: "+myEncryptedText);

    String plainText = encryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
    System.out.println("Decrypted: "+plainText);
 }
}
```

**Output:**

> Encrypted: 
>   fureWQHrflMinY+KBOcNeJyYmQv+7Ung/IclGz3iSBYKqTNdgslADg+TMcfFI/unaqZ/P3kDGPco2jZ4vIhrFw==
>
> Decrypted: Test!email30#password

**Spring Boot Integration:**

You can use `@EnableEncryptableProperties` in your any configuration class or `@SpringBootApplication`. See example:

```
import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableEncryptableProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.company.persistence.entities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = {"com.company.persistence.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**And in any properties/yml file:**

```
email:
    password:
        # DO-NOT-USE/REMOVE THIS
        plain: 'Test!email30#password'
        # use this encrypted one
        encrypted: ENC(fureWQHrflMinY+KBOcNeJyYmQv+7Ung/IclGz3iSBYKqTNdgslADg+TMcfFI/unaqZ/P3kDGPco2jZ4vIhrFw==)

jasypt:
    encryptor:
        password: some_salt
```